# Is it possible to send FAX data over ss7 line using ss7 protocol?

Tags: linux

We send FAX using ISDN protocol.
Is it possible to send FAX data over ss7 line using ss7 protocol? 
If Yes then please tell the FAX data flow architecture for ss7 line. which procedure it used to send FAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can send Fax data over SS7ISUP, not over pure SS7. Look up specs on SS7ISUP for more details.

> The ISUP performs the same function as the TUP (that is, it handles
>   the setup and tear-down of telephone calls) but it is much more
>   sophisticated providing function available with primary rate ISDN.
>   This includes calling and called number notification (or suppression),
>   the ability to control billing (charging) rates, advanced telephony
>   functions such as transfer, and control over whether the voice channel
>   is used for voice, fax, or data.
>
> As with TUP, ISUP messages flow only during the setup and tear-down
>   phases of a call.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wvraix/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wvraix.newss7.doc%2Fthess7protocolstac3.html

Answer (score 0):

As an working example ,using Asterisk it is possible to develop fax server through TDM and IP channels. If TDM is the option, channels should be established using CTI boards. IP channels use G.711 audio encoding or T.38 protocol. In any case your fax server should be integrated to PSTN or MNO via their SS7 gateways.